# How to display the username of a user after successful login in google maps v3 c#?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

I'm actually working on a tracking system project in asp.net c#. I've already implemented the login section and made use of "session" to track the users. I have a map (Google Map v3) that is being displayed on the homepage which shows the user his/her current location after successful login. What i want to do now is retrieve the value of the username and display it on the map. I've tried to keep the value of the username in an html element and then try to access it with JavaScript but alas! That didn't work! Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the username through a WebMethod in c# and then grab it when you generate your marker using ajax. Similar to this:

```
function grabUser() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToMethod,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string User() {
    return userName;
}
```